# SwiftUi line pass with a hstack

Tags: swiftui, hstack

## Hello to all, I have a simple question yet I find not that solutions that seems very complex.

I am looking for a way to make a line break on my Hstack once the screen size is exceeded.

Here is my code:

```
//
//  TrendySection.swift
//  Activiteam
//
//  Created by Theo Marie on 30/04/2022.
//
struct IdentifiableSport: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var name: String
    var icon: String
}


import SwiftUI
struct TrendySection: View {
    var body: some View {
        let trendySports = [
            IdentifiableSport(name: "Tennis", icon: "tennis"),
            IdentifiableSport(name: "Badminton", icon: "badminton"),
            IdentifiableSport(name: "Basketball", icon: "basketball"),
            IdentifiableSport(name: "Football", icon: "football"),
            ]
        VStack(spacing: 12) {
            
        Text("Activités les plus recherchées")
          .font(Font.custom("Poppins-Bold", size: 24))
          .foregroundColor(Color.black)
          .frame(maxWidth: 300, alignment: .topLeading)
          .lineLimit(2)
                HStack(spacing: 32) {
                    ForEach(trendySports) { trendySport in
                        Trendybutton(icon: trendySport.icon, sportName: trendySport.name)
                               }
                }

                  .padding([.top, .bottom, .leading, .trailing], 0)
            }
    }
}

struct TrendySection_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TrendySection()
    }
}
```

[My current rendering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUMpB.png)

[the Figma model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WGXjW.png)

I thank you in advance for your proposal.

Comment: you could try (read-up on) using `LazyVGrid`, with `GridItem`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As someone suggested, you should try to checkout LazyVStack or LazyHStack. Here is some code that may help you.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    let items = [GridItem(.flexible()), GridItem(.flexible()),GridItem(.flexible())]
    
    let data = (1...20).map { "Item #\($0)" }
    
    var body: some View {
        LazyVGrid(columns: items) {
            ForEach(data, id: \.self) { item in
                Text(item)
                    .padding()
                    .background(.green)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I have implemented your code and it works perfectly!
Thank you very much

Comment: Thank you! Please make sure to mark the answer as the correct answer, this will help other people too.